# How to load external file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use this code to change text by click on it, i need to load external file `text.txt` instead of insert it from same page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div3").click(function() {
    changtext();
  });
});

function changtext() {
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "thank you text has been changed";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2">The text will get loaded here</div>
<div id="div3">click me to chang text </div>
```

what i need to change to load text.txt

Comment: `i need to load external file` - as you have tagged the question with `jQuery`,  look up documentation for [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and/or [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) methods - have a go at writing it yourself

Comment: Note: the title is misleading (I think) - because you say *using java*, but your tags and code are *javascript* only - so, is that a mistake on your part?

Comment: Yes i mean JavaScript it is  mistake, but i do not know how i edit it

Comment: I'd edit for you, but someone has tried to make your code a runable snippet for some odd reason - totally pointless edit - I mean, they haven't even fixed your odd indentations!

Comment: I try to use document you provide before i submit my question, but did not success, this code only i successes to  writ it and work fine, but it is not what i need as i need to load file when click it.

Comment: no, you did **not** try using ajax/get - because your code does not use those functions - if you have an issue with code, don't post code that works, but doesn't do what you want and ask someone to do it for you ... show your attempts, you can learn from mistakes, everyone makes them, there's no need to hide them from us

Comment: @D.TAM **I do not know how i edit it** Don't you see the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49683315/edit) link right below the question?

Comment: yes i can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .load method. Also might want to change the title to how to load external file using Javascript with jquery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2">The text will get loaded here</div>
<div id="div3">click me to chang text </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div3').click(function() {
    $('#div2').load('text.txt');
  });
});
</script>
```

text.txt should be in the same directory as the html file. Also, make sure there is text inside the file.

Comment: I try to use this code but did not work, i know the code should be work, i may miss something.

Comment: I updated the post to make it more clear. You can test it by creating a new index.html file, copying the code from my comment into the html file. Then creating a text.txt with some text inside in the same directory and run the html file. Click the div3 and it will change. I tested and it works in firefox.

Comment: Make sure your text.txt file is in the same directory (or change the path), and also that it is not empty.

Comment: Just now i understand why did not work before, i was use Google Chrome so it did not work, when i use Firefox it work, is it normal?

Comment: All my other code work normally with Firefox, i spent hours with Google Chrome and most of the code did not work with it, so i think the code has issues

Comment: Yes, it's normal for the .load method to not work on Chrome when run locally. Chrome has a "same origin policy" which prevents it from reading files of your hard drive. It will work for Chrome users when it's on your server. You can run chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files to allow it for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

JS can read local files (see FileReader()) but not automatically: the user has to pass the file or a list of files to the script with an html .

You can refer: https://www.javascripture.com/FileReader to get more solution.